# How to run a variable where a function that just made console.log was saved?

Tags: javascript

```js
function a() {
  console.log(5);
  return;
}
var x = a;
x();
```

// Line 2 Output: 5         // compiler output read function a ()

// Line 6 Output: undefined // result of execution x ()

---

```
var person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Smith',  
  full: function() {
    console.log(this.first);
  }
};
```

Output: 'john'

```js
var person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Smith',
  full: function() {
    console.log(this.first);
  }
};
person.first = 'pedro';
person.full()
```

// Line 5 Output: 'pedro'

// Line 9 Output: undefined // result of execution x ()

Does anyone explain to me what's happening? Because Output is not:
'john' -> here gives 'pedro' by the seen, the person.first statement executes first that the console.log (this.first)
'pedro' -> here gives undefined, it's the same case as above

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? I can't figure out what your question is nor do I understand what your _"Line x Output:..."_ comments are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question worded strangely, but I will try to answer as best as I can.

```
var person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Smith',  
  full: function() {
    console.log(this.first);
  }
};
```

When a function is defined without a return, undefined will always be returned back to the caller. JavaScript functions always return something.

You would have to state a return if you wanted to use that variable from the function.

You can grab the object's variables through namespacing, in your example, you could do: `person.first`, `person.last`.

And if you wanted the function to return something, you would declare person like so:

```
var person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Smith',  
  full: function() {
    return this.first + " " + this.last;
  }
};
```